# how can I reduce pdf size using pdfbox

Tags: pdfbox

I want to compress output PDF. The code below output was so biger than original file. Can I use compress option?

```
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(in);
PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
doc.addPage(page);
PDImageXObject pdImageXObject = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(doc, bimg, 0.03f);
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true);
contentStream.close(); 
doc.save(outfile);
doc.close();
```

Comment: What format is the original image?

Comment: jpeg image from splited PDF BOX , DPI 200

Comment: @user3741558 The next question would be if it was a jpeg file in the previous PDF. If it was so, then check whether you used the shortcut used in ExtractImages ("unmodified JPEG stream"). If yes, then you should create your JPEG file with `JPEGFactory.createFromStream()`. If extracting from the old PDF and creating the new one is done in the same code, then you could reuse the PDImage object, but do not close the source file before the destination file.